# Failed to start an Appium session, Error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME env variable with the Android SDK root directory path

Tags: appium

Image 1 :

[image]

When I run the following program by testNG getting error as follows,

Image 2 :

[image]

**Error**

**Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.**

```
Environment variable every thing configure properly (i.e)
ANDRIOD_HOME:  D:\android-sdk-windows;

Path :%ANDRIOD_HOME%\tools;%ANDRIOD_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

Comment: Begin with posting the code and error as image

Comment: Looking at your code, what platform are you running on. You have "Andriod" as the String. Perhaps that should be "Android".

Comment: You have a typo in your path. Path :%ANDRIOD_HOME%\tools;%ANDRIOD_HOME%\platform-tools;

ANDRIOD_HOME, but it should be ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 0):

You need to set path to your android sdks as ANDROID_HOME in your IDE, bash_profile and appium app (if using)

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sba53/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`

Answer (score 0):

In your code they is a typo It must be Android-> its  andriod

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sba53/Library/Android/sdk
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

 also set nodejs path upto bin
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```